# Enabling channels leads to SuspiciousFileOperation at /

Tags: reactjs, django, django-channels

I noticed that whenever I enable django channels in my code, I get the following error, when I run the server:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /

The joined path (C:\favicon.ico) is located outside of the base path component.

Error during template rendering
```

Following changes in settings.py produce the error:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "channels",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "core",
    "drf_yasg2",
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "app.wsgi.application"
ASGI_APPLICATION = "app.asgi.application"
```

Following changes in asgi.py produce the error:

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})
```

Comment: Please don't use images of code or error stack. It causes that your problem is not reproducible and doesn't contain the minimal reproducible example necessary. People don't like external links as well, many won't click it. Image linked here is hard to read, it would be way better to include the error here within the question with proper formatting (as you did with code). As you have solved the problem, it can be helpful here for future readers.

Comment: I really appreciate your constructive feedback so thank you for that. I have updated my question, if it can be improved further, I look forward to learning that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was caused by browser cookies, clearing the cookies makes my code work again!